# In Redmine, is there a way to have the fields of duplicate issues update automatically?

Tags: duplicates, redmine

It does not seem to update fields of duplicate issues automatically. It might cause someone to think the issue is not progressing, while the information is added on the duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, duplicate issues do not update any fields automatically between each other.

A commonly used workflow for duplicate issues is to add a *relation* between the original and the new issue indicating that the newer issue *duplicates* the older one. The newer issue then gets *closed* in order to not have appear the same issue twice in the list of open issues, and also to direct the discussion (new information, progress, patches, etc.) to a single issue - the original one.

Here's an [example of a duplicate issue](http://www.redmine.org/issues/8780) on the official redmine issues list.

That being said, you *could* write a plugin which updates certain properties of duplicate issues, though it is not clear to me what exactly you'd like to achieve, and it'll probably be confusing to the users to track the same bug/feature on different issues.

Comment: The reason I had a duplicate issue is that the issue was a child issue for two other issues. If I close the duplicate issue, somebody might think that it is OK to close the parent issue. That would be a problem if the duplicated issue is still open. I will try to write a plugin.